# MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver - Found cycle for field 'variable' in type

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb, spring-data-rest

Below code gives error:
    WARN  MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver - Found cycle for field 'variable'   in type 'Foo' for path 'roo.foo'
    How to resolve this warning ?

```
@Document    
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)    
public class Foo {   

    @Field    
    List<Foo> foo;       

    public List<Foo> getFoo() {   
         if (foo == null)    
             foo = new ArrayList<Foo>();   
         return foo;   
    }

    public void setFoo( List<Foo> foo) {   
         this.foo = foo;    
    }      
}
```

Comment: facing this : WARN  MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver - Found cycle for field 'variable' in type 'Foo' for path ''
org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver$CyclicPropertyReferenceException: Found cycle for field 'variable' in type 'Foo' for path ''

Comment: How did you resolve the warning?

Answer (score 0):

try using `List<?> foo`  instead of `List<Foo> foo`